# Hide 404 error if url contains specific word / PHP

Tags: php, console, http-status-code-404, hide

Is it possible to hide the 404 Error in the console if the url contains a specific word?

Comment: A 404 means not found. Well it can be done in several ways, depending what you use, it might be done with routing if you use framework, and it also can be done from your webserver. More context to the problem you have would be helpful.

Comment: Your question isn't specific. Maybe you can explain in more detail, and include a case example

Comment: My page is built with WordPress. So I can use PHP and Javascript. For all url calls with the word "products" (Example: "mypage.com/products") there should be no error.

Comment: @allgaeu 404 is intended behaviour, if you dont have route who resolves to the page it will throw 404, you could make a global redirect for 404 to resole in the nice page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're basically hijacking the 404 page so you can have dynamic URLS, which means you'll need to invoke the following before you start sending the actual content.

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")
```

Comment: Thanks! It's so simple.